# Adding Winston logging to a React JS application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logging, winston

I want to implement Winston logging on my React application (made using create-react-app).

I have installed Winston:

```
npm install winston
```

I import it into the application app.js:

```
import winston from 'winston';
```

Then attempt to implement a logger:

```
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  format: winston.format.json(),
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'error.log', level: 'error' }),
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'combined.log' })
  ]
});
```

Then:

```
logger.info('Hello from ReactJS');
```

However, when I then go to run the application I get 20+ errors in the browser:

[image]

All suggesting that various modules cannot be found. If I then comment out the logger it loads fine with no errors.
Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Have you tried installing [`winston-react`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-react) instead?

Comment: I did try that first but from looking at the example on the link it also uses Winston (as above) so I got the same problems.

Comment: Probably related [CRA github issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11756). And I'll also leave [this interesting PR in React](https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/pull/5487)

Answer (score 0):

I used **loglevel** instead of winston, and it works as expected. winston is a great logger for nodejs.